# How to insert projected data in aggregation as numberLong value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am doing aggregation sync from one mongo to another and my query below

```
db.users.aggregate([{
            $match: {
                severity: {
                    $in:[1,3]
                }
            }
        },{
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                filterId: '$userId',
                filterType: {$literal: 'PUBLISHER'},
                lastUpdate: { $add: [Date.now()]},
                severityLevel : '$severity'
            }
        }];)
```

After that I am inserting array of data to another database, but 'lastUpdate' field save as double value. How can I insert this field in numberLong type?

Comment: What you want to achieve using `{ $add: [Date.now()]}` ?

Comment: To get timestamp in milliseconds

Comment: That is not the right way. Read [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) before using it in query.

Comment: As per the doc : - Adds numbers together or adds numbers and a date. If one of the arguments is a date, $add treats the other arguments as milliseconds to add to the date.

Comment: Date.now() return number value, why it's not right way?

Comment: `$add` should not be used the way you are trying to use, that is what I was trying to say.